# Cloning javascript object omitting one property

Tags: javascript

What's the best way in JavaScript for returning an object omitting just one or more properties?

I can assign a key to undefined and that works for sure, but what if want to completely get rid of that key?

```
function removeCKey() {
  const obj = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
  return {
    ...obj,
    c: undefined,
  };
}

const myObj = removeCKey();
```

Also, I want to avoid creating an intermediate object where I use the spread operator like this

```
function removeCKey() {
  const obj = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
  const {c, ...rest} = newObj

  return rest;
}

const myObj = removeCKey();
```

Comment: Mutating the object or creating a copy?

Comment: You can `delete obj.c`.

Comment: That works fine @SergiuParaschiv but what if I need to remove a lot of keys?

Comment: FYI, [operator delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: Destructuring:           `const { c, ...result } = obj;
          return result;`

Comment: You make a list of the keys and `delete obj[k]` where `k` is each value in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
function removeKeys() {
  const obj = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c'
  };

  // extract property c in variable c
  // and rest of the value into res 
  let { c, ...res } = obj;

  return res;
}

console.log(removeKeys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `delete` what you don't need:

```
function omit(obj, keys) {
  const newObj = { ...obj };  // shallow copy...
  keys.forEach(key => {
    delete newObj[key];  // ... and `delete`.
  });
  return newObj;
}

omit({a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}, ['c']);
```

outputs

```
{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }
```